# HIbernate saveorupdate not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I am stuck on this for quite a long time now and have tried everything i could.
So, now i come to you.

I have a table `Account` having a `status` column with `acctId` as `primary key`.

Whenever user marks it as suspended from UI we make the `status column` as 31.
We use hibernateTemplate `saveorupdate` method to update this column but to my astonishment some of the record updates just fail as in with no error logs (It prints that it is invoking `saveorupdate` with value as 31 but db status does not change and this happen randomly.

I tried it with 9 accounts and 3 of them did not get updated.
Everything seems to work fine. Another update on another table just after above saveorupdate works.

Code -

```
    acct = manager.load(acctId);
    acct.setStatus(31);
    manager.saveOrUpdate(acct);
```

where `load` and `saveorupdate` are implemented through `hibernatetemplate`.

PS: Method is marked as `@Transactional`.

Please help!

Thanks,
Ouney

Comment: please add some code. the entity, the call of saveordupdate ...

Comment: Added..Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps you can set the hibernate log level to debug, and have a look what happens